# ZipArchive::close returns false

Tags: php, zip

Hi I am attempting to create a new zip file, I have recompiled PHP enabling ZIP and here is my code

```
        if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){ 
          $zip = new ZipArchive;     
          if($zip->open("/home/user1joe/public_html/upload/test.zip",ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)!= true)  {
                 echo "error file did not up upload";
                 exit(0);
          }
          foreach ($_FILES["images"]["error"] as $key => $error) 
                  if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
                        $temp_name = $_FILES["images"]["tmp_name"][$key];
                        $new_name  = $_FILES['images']['name'][$key];
                        var_dump($temp_name);
                        var_dump($new_name); 

                        if(file_exists($temp_name)){
                              $zip->addFile($temp_name,$new_name);
                              move_uploaded_file($temp_name, "upload/".$new_name);
                        } else
                              echo "error file does not exist"; 

                        echo "numfiles: " . $zip->numFiles . "\n";
                        echo "status:" . $zip->status . "\n";
                  }
          $res = $zip->close();
          var_dump($res);
          }
```

$zip->close() is returning false and no zip is being created.

- I get no errors building up to this
- $zip->numFiles shows there are files in the archive
- The folder where I want to create the zip has writable permission

I am a bit lost of what else I can test for, any ideas would be great!

Comment: Shouldn't you have move_uploaded file before archiving it?

Comment: `$zip->close()` returning false is a sign that the zip file could not be saved.  You might not have sufficient permissions to create a file in the location you're trying to.

Comment: Hey guys sorry it's a bit confusing. move_upload is just there to test that I do actually have permissions to create files in the same location as I want to place the zip. The files are stored in the $_FILES["images"]["tmp_name"][$key] location.

Comment: But the zip file may not be in the same directory as the move_uploaded_files. One path is relative, the other absolute

Comment: I doubled check and they are in the same location. I dumped this strategy and used a shell command

Answer (score 1):

zip->close() method do some processing (actual compression, or just getting/writing file attributes), which require that files, added to archive, to exist.
However you are removing input files from the original location with move_uploaded_file() call.